# replacing dots with _ using javascript globally?

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to replace all the dots and spaces in `"`

```
var name = "C. S. Lewis"
```

and replace them with `_`

and convert it into `"C_S_LEWIS"`

this is what i tried but it converts the whole thing into underscores (`_`)

```
var mystring = "C. S. Lewis";
var find = ".";
var regex = new RegExp(find, "g");
alert(mystring.replace(regex, "_"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because dots need to be escaped in regular expressions (unless it's part of a character class). This expression should work:

```
var regex = /[.\s]+/g;

alert(mystring.replace(regex, '_'))
```

It matches a sequence of at least one period or space, which is then replaced by a single underscore in the subsequent `.replace()` call.

Btw, this won't save the new string back into `mystring`. For that you need to assign the results of the replacement operation back into the same variable:

```
mystring = mystring.replace(regex, '_')
```

Comment: I don't think you need the backslash within a [] set (for the . not the \s).

Comment: thanks for your answer, but its removing the spaces and the dots but not replacing them with _

Answer (score 0):

The `.` means 'any character'. Use `\.` to get a literal dot, which means in your `regex` string you'd have to put `\\.` to get a literal underscore followed by a literal dot.  But I'm not sure why you're making a string first - you could just do this:

```
var find = /\./g;
```

Of course, that's not what you're looking for - you want not just any dot, but just the dots followed by spaces.  That's different:

```
var find = /\.\s+/g;
```